# Pandas DataFrame Column rename error.... am I'm being silly?

Tags: pandas, rename, dataframe

So I have two DataFrames each with a number of columns, one is from a new lookup table the other is of already known values stored in my database. The only columns with the same name are `hash` but one has and `id` and the other has `Id` (yes bad naming!) I then call:

```
lookup = lookup.merge(known, on='hash', how='left')
lookup = lookup.rename(columns={'Id':'db_id'})
```

You know to merge them and to update the names so that I don't have to remember which one is `Id` and which is `id`, a few lines earlier I had called

```
known = known.rename(columns={'Hash':'hash'})
```

So that I can preform the hash, all is well and good and right with the world. I then go and change my hashing algorithm, update my database and rerun things. Now, the like

```
lookup = lookup.rename(columns={'Id':'db_id'})
```

doesn't throw an error but results in a very long error string ending in:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures)
   4489                     # no k defined yet

   4490                     pass
-> 4491                 raise e
   4492 
   4493 

TypeError: ("'NoneType' object is not iterable", u'occurred at index hash')
```

to be stored in `lookup`, which is you know a problem. If I change my code to:

```
known = known.rename(columns={'Hash':'hash', 'Id':'db_id'})
lookup = lookup.merge(known, on='hash', how='left')
```

All is again well and right with the world, except I'm very very confused the way I had it before no longer works.

Comment: What do you expect `lookup = lookup(columns={'Id':'db_id'})` to do?  I'm not sure I know that syntax.

Comment: Sorry, when I changed the name of the DataFrame to `lookup` to make it simpler I accidentally deleted the `.rename` after it.

Comment: This looks like a bug fixed in 0.13/master (releasing shortly), but w/o the posted data you are merging its hard to tell.

Comment: Why not use the "suffixes" attribute in the merge method to change set unique names you can work with? 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html